# Does Kingsoft Office Official PPA exist?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, wps-office

Kingsoft Office has better supporting of Microsoft Office than LibreOffice. But it's annoying every time when new release published to download and install it manually.

So, does Kingsoft Office Official PPA exist?

Comment: Kingsoft Office is not open source so it can -never- be better than LibreOffice.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, I use LibreOffice for all my personal documentation, but I get a lot of documents from other people, who use Windows. And talking just about Microsoft Office documents support, truly Kingsoft Office is better. I understand they could change license agreement any time they want.

Comment: Not only that: the software is illegal to use by americans according to their license :)

Comment: technically they could run their own repository - ppas are a specific sort of debian repository. If they want to, they could, but its really something to ask kingsoft

Comment: Whoops, meant to comment here. See my comment to Rinzwind's answer below. His link to the EULA was extremely helpful for me a couple months ago -- I was interested in Kingsoft until I saw their explicit note disallowing US/Canada usage. HOWEVER, that appears to be gone in their most recent EULA -- so that's some progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *So, does Kingsoft Office Official PPA exist?*

No. You need to download the debian installer file each time. WPS does not have an update feature. And since it is closed software it will not end up in the repositories since their license is in violation of any of the values Ubuntu stands for.

*Please read [LICENSE AGREEMENT OF KINGSOFT OFFICE FOR LINUX COMMUNITY VERSION (also called WPS OFFICE FOR COMMUNITY VERSION)](http://www.wps.cn/privacy/unixdistribute/) thoroughly.*

Their license claims you can repack it but several other restrictions make it impossible for anyone to make a PPA: for one how are you going to prevent a North American to download from your PPA?

Comment: Yeah, those are a few interesting terms. No doubt to satisfy something that stops them being sued in America, but pretty weird nonetheless. And it's helpful that half their links don't work.

Comment: made it a bit shorter to keep it to the point. But their license is not very Ubuntu :D

Comment: Just to make a quick note: I believe they've removed the language about North Americans not being able to download/use it. I actually emailed their support team to ask about this a month or two ago and they replied along the lines of "we're going to change that language in the next few weeks." Looking at the link now, it seems like they've changed it. 
Of course, that doesn't address the other possible not-open-source issues some will have. However at least now there isn't explicit dis-allowance of use in the US/Canada.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way, through Ubuntu Software Center.

Once you've installed Kingsoft, in shows up there.

If you download the new version and double-click the download, the Software Center is activated en gives the possibility to upgrade. Just click on that button and there you go.